# How to make statements inside div as invisible on page load using jQuery?

Tags: jquery

On page load I need to make `divGrid` invisible, where div is containing Grid.
In same page there is another division as `divdropdown` containing dropdown of all site names.

Therefore, on change value in the drop down, I need to display `divGrid` `<div>`.

How is this achieved using jQuery?

Comment: `$('select').change(function() { $('#divGrid').show(); });` (modify the `$('select')` as required to suit)

Answer (score 0):

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
  $('.divGrid').hide();
  $('.').on('change',function(){
    $('.divGrid').show();
  });

});
```

Change the selection names as required

Comment: Thanks for reply. I have implemented according to your suggestion. Initially it is hided.But On change in dropdown . It is showing and hided immediately. It is not displayed properly. @Anusha

Comment: I have given Onsubmit form property for drop down list and called Action to filter data in grid. will this effect to above code? - Anusha

Comment: @shaikmansoor yes it will effect. If the page loads again, it will be hidden.

Comment: Then How to manage to display grid data equals with the selected value  from drop down list and hide the data in grid not equals to selected value @Anusha